# Rails - Rendering partial on join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have `Topic` and `Lesson` models. A Topic has_many Lessons and a Lesson belong_to a Topic.

In my **topics_controller.rb** I have

```
@topics = Topic.all
```

and I use `render @topics` in the index view, through the partial **_topic.html.erb**

Untill here, everything's fine.

Now, I want to render in the **home.html.erb** a list of topics with lessons, and use a partial (different from **_topic.html.erb**) to render the html for those elements.

In my **static_pages_controller.rb** I have:

```
def home
  @available_lessons = Topic.joins(:lessons)
end
```

I created a partial **_available_lesson.html.erb** in the views/static_pages folder, and then in the **home.html.erb** file I put `render @available_lessons`.

I expected to get the new partial but Rails keep rendering the old **_topic.html.erb**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just give the full path, `render partial: "available_lesson", collection: @available_lessons`, i'm not sure about the details, but I suspect that when you use the short hand syntax, rails recognize your `@available_lessons` is a collection of `Topic`, that's why it automatically look for `_topic.html.erb` (Just guessing, look it up to make sure)

Comment: it works, thank you very much for the answer and for the details. If you want to create a proper answer I will flag it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just give the full path

```
render partial: "available_lesson", collection: @available_lessons
```

I'm not sure about the details, but I suspect that when you use the short hand syntax, rails recognize your `@available_lessons` is a collection of `Topic`, that's why it automatically look for `_topic.html.erb` (Just guessing, look it up to make sure)